# How to output the result on the same page from IF Else?

Tags: powershell

How can I out put the result from my script on the same page with a good format? currently `if` and `else` are output to console and `Out-GridView`.

```
$PCList = "C:\Scripts\Get-ADComputers\Win7.txt" 

foreach ($PC in Get-Content $PCList) {
    if (-not(Test-Connection -ComputerName $pc -BufferSize 16 -Count 2 -Quiet)) {
        Write-Host "$pc is not reachable" -ForegroundColor "yellow"
    } else {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -ScriptBlock {
            $Session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"
            $Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
            $historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
            $Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) |
                Where-Object {$_.title -like "*KB4019264*"} |
                Select-Object Date,
                    @{name="Operation"; expression={switch($_.operation){1 {"Installation"}; 2 {"Uninstallation"}; 3 {"Other"}}}},
                    @{name="Status"; expression={switch($_.resultcode){1 {"In Progress"}; 2 {"Succeeded"}; 3 {"Succeeded With Errors"}; 4 {"Failed"}; 5 {"Aborted"}}}},
                    Title
        } | Out-GridView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you want the results for all computers in the gridview? Then you need to create objects for the failed connections with the same properties that a successful query produces. I'd suggest changing the `foreach` loop to a `ForEach-Object` loop for that. You may also want to add a field for the hostname to the output, so you can distinguish one computer from the other.

```
Get-Content $PCList | ForEach-Object {
    $pc = $_
    if (-not (Test-Connection -ComputerName $pc -BufferSize 16 -Count 2 -Quiet)) {
        New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
            'Hostname'  = $pc
            'Date'      = $null
            'Operation' = $null
            'Status'    = 'Connection failed'
            'Title'     = $null
        }
    } else {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -ScriptBlock {
            ...
        }
    }
} | Out-GridView
```

Comment: I have over 200 names in the `$pclist`, after i run your suggested script, It only returns me around 60 results including "ping-able" and "un-ping-able" hosts, why it missing the results on rest of host in `$pclist` ?

Comment: Most likely those hosts don't have a hotfix KB4019264 in their history. If you want them to appear as "not installed" you need to check if the pipeline returned a result and create a custom object otherwise.